# Dynamic page title

Tags: panels

I use panels to output my taxonomy term structure. So instead of having one static title for all taxonomies, I need the page title to be the "taxonomy_term_context:title".

In D7 there were modules.
How to deal with dynamic title for panels in Drupal 8?
Are there any hooks?
The panels ui does not seem to handle title from context features.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find anything useful in the web.
I have written a custom module with this hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_panels_build_alter().
 */
function shop_list_page_panels_build_alter(array &$build, PanelsDisplayVariant $panels_display) {
  // Check for panel variant.
  if ("shop_category_list-panels_variant-0" === $panels_display->getConfiguration()['storage_id']) {
    // Set page title.
    $build['#title'] = $build['#title']->create($contexts['taxonomy_term']->getContextData()->getString());
  }
}
```